# Создание директории в андоиде

Tags: android, java

Как создать директорию в андроиде? У меня есть код, который копирует файлы, но, когда я копирую вложенные файлы, выбрасывается исключение. Как я понимаю, это происходит из за копирования файла в несуществующею директорию.

Копирую я так:

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
inputStream = assetManager.open(from);
while ((count = inputStream.read(inputBuffer)) > 0)
    f.write(inputBuffer, 0, count);
f.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new File(directoryPath).mkdir() или new File(directoryPath).mkdirs()
```

Читайте javadoc по [java.io.File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html)

Если идти совсем напролом, то можно дописать перед открытием потока:

```
new File(fileName).getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

**UPD:** в вашем коде ошибка. Дело в том, что теоретически `read` может вернуть `0`, но это не будет означать конец потока. Поэтому, следует сравнивать возвращаемое значение с `-1`, как это описано в документации (как на оригинальную Java, так и для Android): [InputStream.read](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29)

Comment: Посмотрел, думаю то, что надо. А чем отличаются mkdir() от mkdirs()? Я вот не понял.

Comment: mkdir создаёт директорию, а mkdirs создаёт много директорий, если требуется. Например, если у вас в корне нет директории a, то mkdir для пути "/a/b/c" не сможет выполниться, так как /a/b - не существует, а mkdirs создась сначала a, потом создась b, а потом и c.